# Chrome Extension get POST Request Data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the `formData` of a `POST` request with a chrome extension. I am using the following `manifest.json` file and `background.js` file. However, when I console.log the requestBody I cannot see the formData which was sent by the website. How can I get the form elements?

```
manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Form Data",
  "description": "Looks at some form data.",
  "version": "0.9",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

```
background.js

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.method == "POST")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestBody"]
);
```

`Example Response:`

```
{"frameId":0,"initiator":"https://example.com","method":"POST","parentFrameId":-1,"requestBody":{"raw":[{"bytes":{}}]},"requestId":"13910","tabId":430,"timeStamp":1645826234368.5469,"type":"xmlhttprequest","url":"https://www.example.com/api/v4/login"}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify doesn't work with this data so remove it and inspect the variable interactively by setting a breakpoint in [background.js devtools](/a/10258029).

Comment: I think it is not the issue here. Because in the example request, `requestBody` is empty. It should not be empty, there should be `username` and `passsword` data in it. I have tried to `console.log(details.requestBody.formData)` and it does not work too.

Comment: Inspect the request object entirely. Maybe the data is inside `raw`.

Comment: Nope the problem is some kinda security protection mechanism. Chrome does not let you get the formData element since it will include username and passwords and critical information in it.

Comment: Extensions can get this data via a content script anyway so hiding this data in webRequest is useless. Did you inspect the object in devtools? Your console log shows there's `bytes`, which cannot be printed, you need to inspect/use it directly.